# Derivation of the function for the position of a particle given that a constant force acts on the particle which always points to fixed point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors

A particle of mass $m$ is moving with initial velocity *v*. A constant force *F* acts on the particle in a direction which always points to a fixed point *P*. If initially the direction of *v* was perpendicular to *F* and the displacement between *P* and the initial position of the particle was *d* how can I derive the function for the position of the particle.

[image]

Comment: The movement will be a constant circular motion, right?

Comment: What exactly have you tried to do in solving your problem? You should show your work at the vet least.

Answer (score 1):

Statement one:

$$ m\ddot{\vec r}  = ||\vec r-\vec r_0||\hat r = F \hat r $$

is the physics, with statement 2:

$$ \vec v\cdot\hat r = 0 $$

so

$$(\dot{r}\hat{r}+ r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta})\dot{\hat{r}}
=0$$
$$  \dot r \hat{r}\cdot \hat{r} = \dot r = 0 $$

as the initial conditions.

Step one is set $\vec r_0 = 0$ since physics doesn't care about your coordinate origin , step two is to declare this a 2D problem, and step 3 is to work in polar coordinates--opps I already did that. So:

Physics:

$$ m\ddot r = F\hat r$$

$$ \ddot \theta = 0 $$

while the initial condition says:

$$ \dot r = 0 $$
$$ r\dot{\theta} = v_0 $$

Now we could go with the comment "isn't this uniform circular motion", and I liked that. But...on 2nd thought, that requires

$$ m\dot{\theta}^2r = F $$

which is not part of the statement of the problem...so I'm leaving it as an exercise to finish ;-).